# Fréchet Derivative in Integral Operator with Heaviside Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am struggling with the following concept in a rigorous sense. I am writing a paper where a Heaviside function arises and I need to compute the Fréchet derivative. Since I am a math researcher, my question is more on formalism than correctness, as I know a way to make everything correct without calling the below a "Fréchet derivative."

Consider the operator $G:C_0^1(\mathbb{R})\to C_0^1(\mathbb{R})$ given by $G(\psi)(z)=\int_\mathbb{R} J(x,z)H(\psi(x))\,\mathrm{d}x,$ with $\psi'\neq 0$ (say $>0$) when $\psi=0.$ Formally, the notation of a Fréchet derivative makes sense by saying 
$$
G'(\psi)(h)(z)=\int_\mathbb{R}J(x,z)\delta(\psi(x))h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Since $\psi'>0$ when $\psi=0,$ there's an interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ such that $\psi$ is increasing when $\psi\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon).$ Then we can rewrite above as
$$
G'(\psi)(h)(z)=\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{J(\psi^{-1}(x),z)h(\psi^{-1}(x))}{\psi'(\psi^{-1}(x))}\delta(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{J(\psi^{-1}(0),z)h(\psi^{-1}(0))}{\psi'(\psi^{-1}(0))}.
$$
Assume that the space is given the usual norm $||\psi||=||\psi||_{\infty} + ||\psi'||_{\infty}$ to make it a Banach space. Clearly, this output is a legitimate function, but is it called a "Fréchet derivative"? I've tried arriving at this using the definition of a Fréchet derivative. i.e. the unique linear operator $A$ s .t.
$$
G'(\psi)(h)(z)=\lim_{||h||\to 0}\frac{||G(\psi+h)-G(\psi)-Ah||}{||h||}=0.
$$
However, I am unable to show that this holds other than by intuition. Is there a way to show this or is it really just a distributional derivative formalism and I can't really call it a Frechet derivative?

Comment: With the norm you chose you need that $\psi \in C^1$ and for some $c > 0$, $|\psi(x)|\ge c$ for $x$ large enough, thus for $\|h\|$ small enough there are only finitely many zeros around which you can replace $h$ by $h(a)+(x-a)h'(a)$ and $\lim_{\|h\|\to 0}$ becomes $\lim_{h(a),h'(a)\to 0}$ that you'll deal easily with. If your function $\psi$ doesn't satisfy it you'll need to add a $\sup_x |h(x)/\phi(x)|$ term to the norm where $|\psi(x)|\ge |\phi(x)|$ for $x$ large enough.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you are saying with those adjustments, the delta distribution serves as a Frechet Derivative over $C_0^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @reuns : I've been thinking about your comment and I think I understand the idea. But in the definition of the Frechet derivative:
$$
G'(\psi)(h)(z)=\lim_{||h||\to 0} \frac{||G(\psi+h)-G(\psi)-Ah||}{||h||},
$$
how can you justify that this limit is zero? By your comment, the numerator reduces to what you described. But how do we know $|h(a)|=o(||h||)$ or $|h'(a)|=o(||h||)$ in the $C^1$ norm?